Find the asymptote, globlal maxima and inflection points of $e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2}}$
Find the asymptote, globlal maxima and inflection points of  $$e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$
$f'(x) = \frac{-2x}{2\sigma^2} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2}}$
An inflection point is defined to be that point, such that $f'(x)=0$ or $f'(x)$ isn't defined, here, $0$ is one such inflection point.
We now attempt to find a global maximum as $0$ is an inflection point, it's a candidate for the maximal point.
We now verify that it's indeed the global maxima.
$f"(x) = \frac{-2}{2\sigma^2} e^{-x^2} - \frac{4x^2}{2\sigma^2} e^{-x^2}$
$f'(0)= -1$
It's thus a maximal point.
We postulate that an asymptote is $y=0$
We will now prove this
We begin by defining   a horizontal asymptote
$\exists M$ st $x>M \implies |f(x)-L| \leq \varepsilon$
Here $L=0$
It thus follows  that the contrapositive is $\forall M$ , $x<M \implies |f(x)| \leq \varepsilon$
we attempt a proof by contrapositive
so $f(x) > \varepsilon \implies  x<M$
$e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2}} > \varepsilon$
$\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2}> ln(\varepsilon)$
${\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2}}< ln(\frac{1}{\varepsilon})$
$x< \sqrt{{2\sigma^2 \cdot ln(\frac{1}{\varepsilon})}}$
I'm not too sure what to do beyond this, specifically because the contrapositive says for all M, not for specific Ms

Inflection points are where the second derivative vanishes.

Actually, that is only one prerequisite condition. To my understanding, inflection points are those where $f''(x)=0$ and $f''$ is changing sign from positive to negative or vice-versa there. (Even then, this makes the assumption we're working with $\mathcal{C}^2$ functions.)
